# Calculator Class - How can I update displayValue without the user having to select operation type twice?

Tags: c#

Here is my main, the issue i'm having is it doesn't grab the second number the user inputs for calculation unless the user selects the operation twice (Ex: 5+5+, will return 10. but 5+5, returns 5.)

btnNumber_Click event grabs the every number from buttons 0-9

```
namespace SimpleAdd
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string displayString;
        private decimal displayValue;

        private bool newValue;

        private Calculator calc = new Calculator();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnNumber_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (newValue)
            {
                displayString = "";
                newValue = false;
            }
            displayString += ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();
            displayValue = Convert.ToDecimal(displayString);
            txtDisplay.Text = displayValue.ToString();
        }

        private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calc.Add(displayValue);
            newValue = true;
            displayValue = calc.CurrentValue;
            txtDisplay.Text = displayValue.ToString();
        }

        private void Equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (newValue)
                    calc.Equals();
                else
                    calc.Equals(displayValue);
                displayValue = calc.CurrentValue;
                txtDisplay.Text = displayValue.ToString();
                newValue = true;
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException)
            {
                displayValue = 0;
                txtDisplay.Text = "Cannot divide by zero.";
                newValue = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calculator Class, both numbers the user inputs are sent to here when called with "calc.Equals()"

```
namespace SimpleAdd
{
    class Calculator
    {
        public Decimal displayValue;
        public Decimal currentValue;

        public decimal CurrentValue
        {
            get
            {
                return currentValue;
            }
        }

        public void Add(Decimal displayValue)
        {
            currentValue += displayValue;
        }

        public decimal Equals()
        {
            return currentValue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly how calculators of such type work... Not exactly clear what you expect to happen... (I'd recommend you to grab an old real life calculator  to try...) Can you please [edit] question to clarify expected behavior - at which point you expect 5, +, 5 sequence of button clicks to produce 10? Or you are asking for "how to parse math expression in C#" (which would be duplicate and get -10 score to the question due to lack of research)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, the way it is written, on Equals_Click the Add functionality is not called. Add functionality is called only on Plus_Click, hence clicking the Plus, a second time gives the expected result..

Comment: Sorry if I didn't do a great job of explaining it, if a user were to type 5+5 for example and hit enter it returns 5. It will only return 10 if the user were to do the following (5+5+ then click the enter button)

Comment: @Brett Koenig, consider storing both the values to be added and the + operator in variables. and on click of Equals, use  [switch case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) on the operator variable to perform corresponding arithmetic operation. for example: case '+': return x + y;

Comment: @Matt. G I had something like that originally in my old calculator, but I don't know how to store the value after the calculation so the user can input more than 3 numbers. Here was my original program, it erased the value after each calculation (btnEquals_Click event) - https://hastebin.com/umugunulaf.cs

Comment: consider using a list to store the inputs, one for the numbers and one for the operators, take first 2 inputs, apply the first operator, and continue the same process with the rest of the input values..